# How to display employee names with only single 'a' in sql

Tags: sql

i want to display the employee names which having only single 'a' in SQL

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here. Are you trying to do a select against a table with a where clause where there is only a single occurance of the letter 'a' in it?

Comment: This is a legit question?  Why vote to close?

Comment: The question is clear enough, if somewhat *concise*. The only thing lacking is sample data.

Answer (score 4):

Quite easy. You need leading and trailing spaces to ensure the "not a" bits work

```
WHERE
   ' ' + name + ' ' LIKE '%[^a]a[^a]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Employee 
 WHERE LEN(EmployeeName) - LEN(REPLACE(EmployeeName,'a','')) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select <emp_name> from <emp_table> where emp_name='%a%';
```

LIKE wildcards

- _(underscore) implies just one character
- % implies zero or more than one character

Comment: This will be true for `'aaa'` which is more than one `a`

Comment: dude then use this '%[^a]a[^a]%'   ^ implies any character except the one that comes after it in the query.

Comment: Also need leading and trailing spaces added because a name with 'a' at the start or end won't match. Try it...